# Initializing C arrays with __auto_type

Tags: gcc, type-inference

I tried to initialize an array using `__auto_type` in GNU C, but this seems to be a syntax error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   __auto_type a[] = {1,2,3,4};
   printf("%d",a[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

As a workaround, I can define a variadic macro to initialize the array using `typeof`, but this is more cumbersome:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define infer_array_type(a,b,...) typeof(b) a[] = {b,__VA_ARGS__}

int main() {
   infer_array_type(a,1,2,3,4);
   printf("%d",a[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

Is it not possible to initialize arrays in GNU C using `__auto_type` instead of `typeof`?

Comment: The [docu](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) states `the declaration must declare only one variable, whose declarator must just be an identifier, the declaration must be initialized, and the type of the variable is determined by the initializer` And the error message says `'__auto_type' requires a plain identifier as declarator` Doesn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In GNU C, it is possible to define a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that returns an array, so the array can be initialized using `__auto_type`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define infer_array_type(b,...) ({typeof(b) a[] = {b,__VA_ARGS__}; a;})

int main() {
   __auto_type a = infer_array_type(1,2,3,4);
   printf("%d",a[0]);
   return 0;
}
```